# Is the set of limit points of a field is closed?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, measure-theory

I just started reading measure theory. After reading the monontone class theorem I wondered if the following is true? If $F$ is a field (closed under finte unions and complements) over a set $S$ and $T$ is the set of limit points of all possible increasing and decreasing sequences of sets in F. Then is $T \cup F $ a monotone class (and hence the smallest monotone class containing the field)?

I 'think' the answer is yes.It is same as showing that for any  limit point of $T$, there is sequence in $F$ converging to it.  If I take an increasing sequence  $\{A^{i}\}$ in $T$, then I can assume without loss of generality that for each(all) $A^{k}$ in  $\{A^{i}\}$  there is an increasing sequence $A_{j}^{k}$ converging to it or for each there is a decreasing sequence converging to it. Assuming the former I am able to show that the limit point is indeed in T again by constructing a sequence consisting one term each from the increasing sequences. Please help me show it for the other case.